# Is indoor automatic positioning possible with AR?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, navigation, indoor-positioning-system

i read a lot of projects about indoor navigation but all of them require to set the start location and every time the user need initially to be in this location, in some cases it is not beneficial such as for blind users, is there a way to detect the position automatically using the available SDK such as ARCore and ARKit or this technology still doesn't exist?!!